# Is central manifold theorem applicable on linear dynamical systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, manifolds, dynamical-systems

I wondered if we could apply the central manifold theorem to a linear dynamical system. I tried to solve the most general case.

Having a system such as:

$$
\dot{x} =  -x + f(x,y) \\
\dot{y} =  -y + g(x,y) \\
$$

Let's apply the central manifold theorem:

$$
y = h(x) = \sum_{n>2}h_n x^n \\
\partial_x h(x) = n \sum_{n>2}h_n x^{n-1} \\
\dot{y} = \partial_x h(x)\dot{x} = (n \sum_{n>2}h_n x^{n-1})(-x + f(x,y)) \\
= n\sum_{n>2}h_n x^n + f(x,y) n \sum_{n>2}h_n x^{n-1} 
$$

On the other hand, we know that

$$
\dot{y} = - \sum_{n>2}h_n x^n + g(x, y)
$$

Now let's apply this to the linear system of choice:

$$
\dot{x} = -x + y \\
\dot{y} = -y +  x
$$

where $f(x,y) = y$ and $g(x,y) = x$

replacing $f(x, y) = y = h(x)= \sum_{n>2}h_n x^n$ would gives us

$$
n\sum_{n>2}h_n x^n + n (\sum_{n>2}h_n x^n)(\sum_{n>2}h_n x^{n-1}) = 
 -\sum_{n>2}h_n x^n + x^1
$$
This equality is not met since there's a $x^1$ term on the right-hand side, which means that it's not possible to have a central manifold on a lower dimension (1d).
I also tried it with an example of a system that has $wx^1$ so I can set $w=0$ to overcome this problem.
I ended up having all the coefficients equal zero in the end: $h_i=0, i >0 $

I don't know how general is my conclusion, can we apply the central manifold theorem to Linear systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only applies if the eigenvalue zero has its eigenvector along the $x$ axis, $(1,0)^T$. In the system that you give, the zero eigenvalue has its eigenvector along the diagonal, $(1,1)^T$. So the expansion has to start as $y=x+h(x)$, which ends up with $h=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you recommend a reference? In Wiggins, I didn't see such conditions. Or maybe I didn't check in detail.

Comment: In the manual exploration of non-trivial cases it is assumed that the space is linearly transformed so that the zero eigenvectors or the full eigenbasis line up with coordinate directions. With CAS this should not be necessary.